# Adjusting font size in Featureplot

Tags: text, resize, caret

I have generated an image that I am largely happy with, but would like to manipulate the font size. Happy using ggplot, but not sure how to carry over this graph into ggplot and alter it within this package. This is the code I have used:

```
library(caret)
plotFvP<-featurePlot(x = Top_pred_FVP[,1:5],
        y = Top_pred_FVP$Tissue, 
        plot = "pairs",
        cex=0.5,
        ## Add a key at the top
        auto.key = list(columns = 2))
plotFvP
```

[FeaturePlot_Image_Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cG1Eq.jpg)